# creating and manip'ing sets of form vars using arrays and loops

Tags: php

I often have long lists of input vars to process, and want to process them looping thru arrays.

So instead of:

```
a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = k = l = m = n = o = p = q = r = s = t = u = v = w = x = y = z = '';
```

and then maybe later on doing something like:

```
$a = sanitize_text($a);
$b = sanitize_text($b);
$c = sanitize_text($c);
...
$z = sanitize_text($z);
```

I could instead:

```
$input_vars = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
```

and then simply:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($input_vars); $i++){
${$input_vars[$i]} = '';
}
```

and then later,

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($input_vars); $i++){
${$input_vars[$i]} = sanitize_text(${$input_vars[$i]});
}
```

and however else I might need to manip the input vars. But I keep getting Undefined Variable warnings with these types of examples. So what am I doing wrong here to be able to use arrays to create and manipulate sets of form variables?

Comment: where you are getting error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the data in the array instead of splitting up into separate variables. Then you have all these tools at your disposal for manipulating the dataset: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php.
More important, you don't risk overwriting existing variables and you won't get any warnings about undefined variables.

Like this:

```
// Initialize the array with empty values
$input_vars = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
$input_vars = array_fill_keys($input_vars, '');

// Do something with the data
foreach ( $input_vars as $key => &$value ) {
  $value = sanitize_text($value);
}
```

Use the `foreach` construct to loop through arrays.